# Seeding a secure random number in java

Tags: java, random, prng

Will two [`java.security.SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) instances which are seeded with the same value initially give the same sequence of random numbers?

I am asking this because I want the same sequence of random numbers in both the client and the server. What if both of them are using the same seed value. Will the sequence be the same, or is there any way that the sequence can be made the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):

> If two instances of `Random` are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers.

Comment: please read the question carefully I am using secure random and you are talking about random.

Comment: `SecureRandom` is a child class of `Random`, I believe this quote from the API still applies. By the definition of a seed, it would follow that two random generators with the same seed would provide the same output - that's the entire point of the seed.

Comment: Just to be clear, the behavior of `java.security.SecureRandom` is depends on the selected implementation, while the behavior of `java.util.Random` is as described.

Answer (score 2):

> What if both of them are using the same seed value. Will the sequence be the same?

No, they definitely won't. At least not in Oracle's Java 7 SDK implementation. See my sample code [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020158/seeding-java-security-securerandom-unnecessary). It appears that the implementation may elect to use additional sources of randomness, in addition to the provided seed.