# seeding java.security.SecureRandom unnecessary?

Tags: java

I am using Java 1.7 and as the code below demonstrates (compiled with Oracle's Java 7 compiler in Ubuntu) seeding **java.security.SecureRandom** appears to be unneccessary as the code produces two different BigIntegers for the starting value of the two pseudo-random sequences:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class SessionIdTest {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
    long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        {
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            random.setSeed(seed);
            BigInteger a = new BigInteger(130, random);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
        {
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            random.setSeed(seed);
            BigInteger a = new BigInteger(130, random);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

What's the purpose of **setSeed** then? Or is **SecureRandom** also using, in addition to the seed, some other source of randomness?

Comment: What is your `SecureRandom` implementation?. Get it with `random.getAlgorithm()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc says:

> Many SecureRandom implementations are in the form of a pseudo-random number generator (PRNG), which means they use a deterministic algorithm to produce a pseudo-random sequence from a true random seed. Other implementations may produce true random numbers, and yet others may use a combination of both techniques.

So, counting on a secure random to generate a deterministic sequence of values by seeding it won't necessarily work, as documented.

Answer (score 2):

JavaDoc says:

Reseeds this random object, using the eight bytes contained
in the given `long seed`. **The given seed supplements,
rather than replaces, the existing seed.** Thus, repeated calls
are guaranteed never to reduce randomness.

Comment: OP is seeding a new SecureRandom instance each time. So the seed doesn't have any previous seed to supplement.

Comment: hm, you are right, also it seems like SecureRandom ignores 0 as a seed (based on Oracle JDK 7 sources), so `setSeed(0L)` call does not make sense at all

Comment: @hoaz I updated my code to use System.currentTimeMillis as seed, same results. Seeding both SecureRandoms with the same seed generates different sequences.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus it will depend on the default `SecureRandom` implementation on your system. Check it with something like `random.getAlgorithm()`. For example, for `SHA1PRNG` both results would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Seeding a `SecureRandom` by calling `java.security.SecureRandom#setSeed` is not necessary, and actually, **shouldn't be done unless you have a really good source of entropy** and `java.lang.System#currentTimeMillis` definitely is not one.

Now, from your example where it was producing two different outputs even when the seed was the same. It is a behaviour that I observed in the `DRBG` `SecureRandom` implementation in Java 10, where both random numbers produced will differ during one execution but will remain constant if the program restarts:

```
public class SessionIdTest {

    public static void main (String args[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        // Hardcoded seed to evidence the deterministic behavior when the program restarts.
        long seed = 1000;
        {
            SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("DRBG");
            random.setSeed(seed);
            BigInteger a = new BigInteger(130, random);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
        {
            SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("DRBG");
            random.setSeed(seed);
            BigInteger a = new BigInteger(130, random);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

So the previous will always generate something like this:

```
724996208419722369188940556616693042555
796664555436785984208644362540465534270
```

And the differing values in one execution have its cause in a global state being updated every time a `DRBG` implementation is created.

Now, if you try the `SHA1PRNG` implementation, both random numbers will be the same and they will remain constant through program restarts:

```
public class SessionIdTest {

    public static void main (String args[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        // Hardcoded seed to evidence the deterministic behavior when the program restarts.
        long seed = 1000;
        {
            SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            random.setSeed(seed);
            BigInteger a = new BigInteger(130, random);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
        {
            SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            random.setSeed(seed);
            BigInteger a = new BigInteger(130, random);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

So the previous will always generate something like this:

```
251586625089438840547467272692377284989
251586625089438840547467272692377284989
```

Finally, in both cases you can confirm that there is a deterministic behavior based on the provided seed, so, **do not seed these `SecureRandom`s manually unless you have a very good source of entropy and again, the current time is not one!**. Just let them seed themselves which is safer.